# How to get the last records that match a specific element value using xslt?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have an xml with a list of cars  records that look like this

```
 <Car>
    <color>red</color>
    <type>toyota</type>
   <status>done</status>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <color>green</color>
    <type>mazda</type>
    <status>done</status>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <color>yellow</color>
    <type>ford</type>
  <status>working</status>
  </Car>
  <Car>
    <color>green</color>
    <type>mazda</type>
    <status>pending</status>
  </Car>
```

I'm currently  getting the last Car records like this

```
<Cars>
      <Car> 
          <xsl:copy-of select="//Car[last()]"/>
      </Car>       
  </Cars>
```

I want to see if is possible to get the last car records that match my element value

Example

From the xml example above I want to get the last car records that doesn't contain pending status so my output look like this.

This is the last record that match my criterial

```
 <Car>
    <color>yellow</color>
    <type>ford</type>
  <status>working</status>
  </Car>
```

And also  that only have the records I want like this.

```
<Cars>
<Car>
        <color>yellow</color>
      <status>working</status>
      </Car>
<Cars>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it simply like this :

```
<Cars>
  <Car> 
      <xsl:copy-of select="//Car[not(status='pending')][last()]"/>
  </Car>       
</Cars>
```

Comment: You can test it here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcxU

Comment: what I can do  if I only want to get the color  and the status so output look like this  <Cars><Car>
    <color>yellow</color> <status>working</status>
  </Car><Cars>

Comment: Read a book or tutorial on how XSLT works?

Comment: what book or tutorial you recommend me to read to help me with this . thank you

Comment: I have this book and find it's a good reference: XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 Programmer's Reference, 4th Edition by Michael Kay

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Also , I was able to figure out the problem :)